# Inserting DateTime value into MS SQL using golang

Tags: go

I am trying to insert a DateTime value into a MS SQL table using golang.  The SQL table is this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TimeSample (
    ModifiedDate datetime
);
```

The golang code I have is this:

```
func timeSample(db *sql.DB) (error) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    var err error

    t := time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)
    fmt.Println(t)
    tsql := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO [dbo].[TimeSample] ([ModifiedDate]) VALUES ('%s');",time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339))

    // Execute non-query
    result, err := db.ExecContext(ctx, tsql)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error inserting new row: " + err.Error())
        return err
    }

    fmt.Println(result)

    return nil
}
```

I am getting the following error when trying to insert:

**2018-04-20T10:39:30-05:00
2018/04/20 10:39:30 Error inserting new row: mssql: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
exit status 1**

Any idea on how I should format this to work for MS SQL?

Comment: Just use parametrized SQL and let the driver take care of the conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, what you should do is to use parametrized SQL - it not only takes care of converting time values to correct format it also protects agains SQL injection attack. Usually SQL parameters are represented by `?` but some drivers use `$1` or `:name` so check the driver's documentation. And your code would then be like:

```
tsql := "INSERT INTO [dbo].[TimeSample] ([ModifiedDate]) VALUES (?)"
result, err := db.ExecContext(ctx, tsql, time.Now())
```

Note that you don't want to have terminating `;` in the SQL string too.